# Bootstrap 4 column doesnt not float right - has space from right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, css-float

my right sidebar has space from right.It doesnt float right.you can see on this link:

http://www.migrate666.deniz-tasarim.site/2020/02/25/american-airlines-reconciles-with-qatar-airways/

```
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2" id="right-sidebar" style="background-color:orange; float: right; right: 0!important; width: 100%;">

        <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

    </div>
```

custom.css:

```
#right-sidebar {
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gone through your site and you have applied width 1280px for container-fluid forcefully. That's why both inner div's (div with class col-md-10 and col-md-2) adjusting their width as per the width of the container-fluid.

**In your *style.css line 580* below is the code. if you comment on this line. it will work.**

```
.container-fluid.single-post {
    width: 1280px;
}
```

See the below image for reference
[image]